# Python Multithreading - How to execute a function as soon as the first thread finishes?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am working with `Python threading` module to execute the same function in parallel two times, but with different arguments. I want to display the results as soon as one of the thread finishes, and then display the results of the second thread when it finishes. I am trying to do it by putting the results of the function which is being called in a **queue** and then waiting for the values in the main thread. The code I'm using is the following:

```
import threading
import queue
import time

q = queue.Queue()
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=some_func, args=(q,0))
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=some_func, args=(q,1))

thread1.start()
thread2.start()

first_result = q.get()
print(first_result)


second_result = q.get()
print(second_result)


def some_func(queue: queue.Queue, val: int):
    time.sleep(val*2 + 5)
    queue.put(val)
```

Now it is waiting for both threads to finish execution and prints out the result at the same time. Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you are not right about threads prints results at the same time now. 0 printing after 5 seconds, and 1 after 7 seconds

Comment: When I run your program (modified to increase the difference in time between how long each thread takes) it very clearly does _not_ print both results at the same time. It prints them as they become available. Same is true if I switch the order in which they are started. Is that not the behavior that you wanted?

Comment: Yes, you are totally correct. In fact, this is a simple example but in my real code I don't know how much time each function call takes to execute, and when I wrote the question those two calls were printing the results at the same time because the execution time was exactly the same. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 2):

`Queue.get()` blocks until there is a result available in the queue. This means that the main thread may waits indefinitely until both threads had finished executing and added their results to the queue. However, you can use `timeout` to confirm that it allows the main thread to check for new results in the queue at regular intervals, without blocking indefinitely.

Try this:

```
thread1.start()
thread2.start()

# Loop until both threads have finished
while thread1.is_alive() or thread2.is_alive():
    # Check for new results in the queue every 0.1 seconds
    try:
        result = q.get(timeout=0.1)
        print(result)
    except queue.Empty:
        pass
```

`print(f"[{time.asctime()}] Result: {result}")`, I used this to confirm that they don't print at the same time.

output:

> ```
> [Mon Dec 19 22:31:07 2022] Result: 0
> [Mon Dec 19 22:31:09 2022] Result: 1
> ```